# Align button to the center bottom of its container

Tags: html, css

I have two div columns, and a button inside each column. I want each button align to the center bottom of each column. So far I can get it in the center or at the bottom, but not for both.

```css
.rr_centerbottom1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-g header">
  <div class="pure-u-12-24">
    <!-- colomn 1 -->
    <a href="test.html" class="pure-button rr_centerbottom1" type='button'> Info</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-12-24">
    <!-- colomn 1 -->
    <a href="test2.html" class="pure-button rr_centerbottom1" type='button'>Boek nu</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use flexbox:

```css
.header {
  min-height: 180px;
  display: flex;
}

.header > div {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-g header">
  <div class="pure-u-12-24">
    <!-- colomn 1 -->
    <a href="test.html" class="pure-button rr_centerbottom1" type='button'> Info</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-12-24">
    <!-- colomn 1 -->
    <a href="test2.html" class="pure-button rr_centerbottom1" type='button'>Boek nu</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oe6bfdcL/)**

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I tried this, but I can't get it work. Your jsFiddle  example is want I want, but I need to get this work with me. Prolly there is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this??

```css
.rr_centerbottom1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.pure-button {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pure-u-12-24 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-g header">
  <div class="pure-u-12-24">
    <!-- colomn 1 -->
    <p class="rr_centerbottom1"><a href="test.html" class="pure-button" type='button'> Info</a>
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-12-24">
    <!-- colomn 1 -->
    <p class="rr_centerbottom1"><a href="test2.html" class="pure-button" type='button'>Boek nu</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, you want to have the links in the bottom of each column, but centered of that each column.

Since i see you already using position: absolute and some kind of GRID system, which probably doesnt use flexbox already, you can try this:

```
.rr_centerbottom1 {
  display: block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    bordeR: 1px solid blue;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 180px;
}
.pure-u-12-24 {width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left;overflow: hidden;position: relative; bordeR: 1px solid red;}
```

Basically you are giving the links a left and right property, to strecth it to full width, and then give it a text align center. If the button is styled button div, you can make it a displaY: inline-block and nesting it in another div that has the left: 0 and right: 0. Btw you could also use width 100%.

Here is a jsfiddle, I added borders to make it clear: https://jsfiddle.net/aLut9pg9/3/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast answer. I just tried this, but i can''t get it work.  However, I see your jsfiddle, which does exactly what i want.